# How can I efficiently store and retrieve tree-structured data in a database?

Tags: sql, database

I'd like to write a note-taking application for the browser. A user has an account, and can create folders, subfolders, subsubfolders, and so on, and notes that go anywhere in that folder structure.

I'm having trouble imagining an efficient way to store and retrieve that information, though (both on the server and ideally cached within the user's browser), and Googling for information has left me a little confused. Is this really as complex a problem as some of the information out there implies, or am I missing something?

Would it be out of the question to do a simple `SELECT * WHERE user_id = ?`, send that to the user, and have client-side code construct the tree from the full flat list of notes and folders?

Comment: Just have one table for NotesFolders and have a ParentID field that links the folder to the one above it in the tree.  If the ParentID is null then its a root folder.  Or maybe make all Root Folders inherit from ID 1.

Comment: The efficiency of a storage and retrieval of a semi-structured data is heavily dependent on queries/commands you want to perform. Could you be more specific about your expected workload?

Comment: Search for "adjacency list" and "recursive query".

Comment: It can be done with a parent and child id showing a looping path between the records but it is inefficient in Sql.  Org structures in a database are done this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea would be possible, but not very efficient. Imagine you have a user with 10.000 notes and subfolders. If you use your query, everytime the user logs in, all of this information will be downloaded - even if he just wants to edit one note.

I think the best way to do it, is to give each folder and note a unique ID and a parent_id field. If the user creates a subfolder, this subfolder gets its own ID and the parent_id will be the unique ID of the parent folder. 
If the notes /folders are on the top level (have no parent) you can assign a special parent_id to identify them.

Doing it this way has some advantages:
You can load the data only if the user needs it. If your user doesn't open a folder, there is no need to download all of the notes in that folder. 
As soon as he opens the folder, you can simply call `SELECT * WHERE parent_id = id` and retrieve all subfolders and notes in that folder.